# Task scheduling when calling external method

Tags: c#, async-await

I have the following extension which allows me to force a timeout on a task.

```
public static async Task<T> TimeoutAfter<T>(this Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeSpan, string message = null)
{
    if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeSpan)))
        return await task;
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException(message);
    }
}
```

I have the following Task:

```
private async Task<string> TestTask(PageData page)
{
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    return "teststring";
}
```

When I call the task using the following I get the intended result.

```
var teststring = await TestTask()
                .TimeoutAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), "timeout message");
```

I issue I am having is that when I call a method in an external library (in this case a c++ CLR Class library), the code inside TimeoutAfter() is never reached and the task never timeouts.  I can fix the issue by using Task.Factory.StartNew() (below), passing a callback to the long running task and creating my Task.Delay task before exectution of the main task starts, but this won't work as an extension.

```
private async Task<T> Timeout<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskFunc)
{
    var taskWait = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => taskFunc());

    if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, taskWait))
        return await (await task);
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException("timeout");
    }
}
```

Why does it appear that the code in TimeoutAfter() is only executing when certain content is in the task it is extending?  What functionality can I add to the extension to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Are you doing this in a Windows Forms or WPF UI, by any chance? Can you produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem? It doesn't help that we don't know anything about the method you're calling - is it asynchronous?#

Comment: You should be aware, this isn't really a "Timeout" in the traditional sense.  Your task does not get aborted, only your wait times out.. the task will continue going and if it's an infinite loop or some other long running task it may have very strange side-effects.  You probably also won't know if exceptions get thrown in that task after the timeout.

Comment: @JonSkeet The code is being executed is in a console app, the method being called in the task is calling a method in a c++ CLR class library, which in turn calls external dlls associated with an imaging library.  Are there certain conditions in which a task will be executed syncronously and the extension will not get called?

Comment: I believe @JonSkeet is on the right track. Check how your failing code is called. If there's any use of `Wait` or `Result`, you're probably running into a [classic deadlock issue](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html) that I describe on my blog. As a simple test, add a `.ConfigureAwait(false)` to every `await` expression in `TimeoutAfter` and see if that works.

Comment: @StephenCleary Im not sure how this applies in this case as there is no UI thread to block.  The code in the extension is never executed when I call the underlying library.  The issue is extending the task in such a way that the extension code is called regardless of the content of the main task

Comment: @jimmyjambles: Please post a minimal, reproducible example.

Answer (score -2):

I think your main issue is that you just don't even start your task when you try with extension method.

A `Task` is fully async and [must be started](http://dotnetcodr.com/2014/01/01/5-ways-to-start-a-task-in-net-c/) to reach its code. One way to start a task is using StartNew as you tried with the factory.

But you can also just call the `Start` method. The only thing you have to be warned is that if a start has already been started or is already finished, you will get an exception when calling Start.

So, I think your solution can be :

```
public static async Task<T> TimeoutAfter<T>(this Task<T> task, TimeSpan timeSpan, string message = null)
{
    if(task.Status != TaskStatus.Running && task.Status != TaskStatus.RanToCompletion){
       task.Start();
    }
    if (task == await Task.WhenAny(task, Task.Delay(timeSpan)))
       return await task;
    else
    {
        throw new TimeoutException(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: You never need to explicitly start an `async` task with `Start`

Comment: Once you hold a reference to Task it has already started, the issue I am having is that no code in the extension is called with certain base tasks